# Spreadsheet locale

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, setlocale

I use to set my Google spreadsheet's primary language to Chinese, then I changed it to English. Everything is changed to English except the error messages when I run my script. I have tried to set to other languages like French but the error messages are still in Chinese.

Comment: Scripts have their own locale, did you change those too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As have been mentioned by Robin, you can try to use local settings in spreadsheet:

File->Spreadsheet Settings

[image]

Or you can try to do it programatically and use [setSpreadsheetLocale](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setSpreadsheetLocale(String)). That's all the language-related solution we can think of.